# Google analytics not working in ios app

Tags: ios7, google-analytics

i'm using google analytics v3 in ios app(ios7).I insatlled libraires and framweworks.I follwed the instructions from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/ .But google analytics is not working from the logger i found "INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.06 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher hitsForDispatch] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:281): No pending hits."

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps missing the send ?

After initialising the tracker:

```
[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-xxxx-x"];
```

Try this example:

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"appview", kGAIHitType, @"Home Screen", kGAIScreenName, nil];
[tracker send:params];
```

Answer (score 1):

i ran into the same issue. i was under the impression that by adding and configuring the framework i was all set to go, but this isn't the case.

i had to do either one of the following:

1. send events (@sjoerd perfors answer)
2. adding at least 1 [screen measurement](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/#screen-tracking) (e.g. `self.screenName = @"posting details";`)

at this point this warning disappeared.